# Python folder imports error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named xxx ( When running a sub module)

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

so I have a folder structure:

```
project folder/
  log/
    __init__.py
    logger.py
  src/
    test.py
  main.py
```

The code in each script:

**logger.py**

```
def logs():
 print("This logged a movement")
```

****init**.py**

```
from logger import *
```

**test.py**

```
from log import logger

def helloWorld():  
 logger.logs();  
 print("Hello world")
```

**main.py**

```
from src import test
test.helloWorld()
```

Now if I run `main.py` the output is:

```
This logged a movement
Hello world
```

but if i try run the test.py script i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\cparnell\Documents\Prac\src\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from log import logger
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'log'
```

Anyone know why I cannot run the test script and how to get it to run?

Comment: Im also very new to Python so im guessing ive possibly setup something incorrectly

Comment: Related: [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14132789/11082165). The answers there cover some common confusions between scripts vs modules and packages vs directories.

Comment: Do you intend `src` and `log` to be two top-level packages? Also, do note that imports don't navigate directories -  they _only_ work by searching the import path. `import X` doesn't mean "look for `X` in the same folder", it means "search the import path for a top-level module name `X`"

Comment: Can you provide more information on how you run python with the script? My assumption is that the package is not discoverable because it's not in the PYYTHONPATH  environmental (https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH)

Comment: My previous comment might be a correct solution to your problem, but the post in @Brian61354270 's comment is actually a good read for you to avoid this situation in the future.

Comment: Im just running it through SV code 'Run Python File'

Comment: will have a read! thanks for quick response.